# Как  создать архив, используя только php?

Tags: php, linux

Возможно ли только при помощи php создать архив на веб-сайте ОС linux. Что я хочу:

1. Создать архив. ОС debian. Нужно заархивировать папку, лежащую в корневой директории сайта. Примерные пути:

   ```
   скрипт => сайт\папка\папка\папка\скрип.php
   директория => сайт\нужная_папка
   ```
2. Скачать.
3. Удалить архив.

Кроме стандартных функции ничего использовать нельзя. Как можно его заархивировать?

Comment: @avengerweb, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Если архиватор установлен на машине, можно просто запустить его, передав соответствующие параметры. Кроме того, думаю, наверняка есть модули для PHP, которые позволяют архивировать. Для Питона, например, они вообще входят в стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: Это никак не учебное задание. Мне лишь нужно узнать, как можно создать архив БЕЗ дополнительных расширений. Ну или возможно ли такое вообще...

Comment: А **tar** чем не подходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Вот](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/zip.examples.php) Вам вполне стандартный класс... Возможно это расширение нужно будет включить в php.ini. Хотя у меня оно и без того работает.

Comment: Я не уверен что этот вариант будет работать на linux. Сейчас проверю

Comment: @avengerweb, у самого линукс. Всё работает. Версия php 5.4.6

Comment: Вообще-то, это часть стандартной библиотеки PHP. Только там написано, что нужно компилировать с определенными условиями. Может, у Вас уже все есть.

Comment: @mikillskegg, возможно. Ну на крайний случай можно будет запустить системную команду tar или zip. Она вроде бы практически во всех дистрибутивах есть из коробки (хотя не уверен). Просто автор топика хотел использовать только лишь php.